# Use one main class has all classes that I need in my components. Is that bad way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have question about building projects in Angular 7.

I have a many of duplicate classes that used in every component. I thought I make one class has all of classes that I need , instead of importing all these classes in every component.

This will make me controlling on the project easily. But I don't know if this bad way or good way? is  It consumes a lot memory and  resources or no?

EX My main class "AppImports" :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Router ,  ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router"
import { Platform,MenuController, ModalController , AlertController, ToastController, PopoverController, ActionSheetController ,  NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
import { Language } from './language';
import { Display } from './display';
import { Api } from './api';
import { Buttons } from './buttons';
import { Animations } from './animations';

@Injectable()
export class AppImports {

    constructor(
        public platform: Platform,
        public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        public statusBar: StatusBar,
        public keyboard: Keyboard,
        public router: Router,
        public activRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        public menu: MenuController,
        public modals: ModalController,
        public alerts: AlertController,
        public toasts:ToastController,
        public pops: PopoverController,
        public sheets: ActionSheetController ,
        public navs: NavController,
        public lang: Language,
        public display: Display,
        public api: Api,
        public button: Buttons,
        public animation: Animations
    ){}




}
```

In my component I imported only one class "AppImports" that has all of my classes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppImports } from '../imports/app-imports'



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],

})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    public app :AppImports,
  ) {


    this.app.menu.open();

  }



}
```

so, Is it bad way or good way?

Answer (score 1):

In each component just import what you need in this component. You can import `AppImports` in your component if all classes of it you really need.